# cloud computing security concerns

Tags: security, cloud

This is my concern about cloud computing, do you agree with me ?

Does cloud computing mean that give your data to us and we will protect them against cyber attacks?

There are many examples of security breaches even in large and famous public web sites so how should people dare to risk and put their crucial data in another place that can be accessed by some accidental reasons?

If it is not for high important data so why people in this industry claim that all enterprises will soon move to cloud services ?

If I'm wrong please help me grow my knowledge.

Comment: Both opinion-based and off-topic for StackOverflow. security.stackexchange.com is a place for this kind of questions but I guess it would be closed as opinion-based there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most significant challenge of Cloud is security. Gaining the trust of a large user base is critical for the future of cloud computing. It’s unrealistic to expect that a public cloud will provide a suitable environment for all applications. Highly sensitive applications related to critical infrastructure management, health-care applications and others will most likely be hosted by private clouds.

Many real-time applications will probably still be confined to private clouds. Some applications may be best served by a hybrid cloud setup. Such applications could keep sensitive data on a private cloud and use a public cloud for some of the processing.

The Software as a Service (SaaS) model faces similar challenges as other online services required to protect private information, such as financial or health-care services. In this case, a user interacts with cloud services through a well-defined interface. In principle, therefore, it’s less challenging for the services provider to close some of the attack channels.

Still, such services are vulnerable to DoS attacks and malicious insiders. Data in storage is most vulnerable to attack, so devote special attention to protecting storage servers. The data replication necessary to ensure continuity of service in case of storage system failure increases vulnerability. Data encryption may protect data in storage, but eventually data must be decrypted for processing. Then it’s exposed to attack.

The Infrastructure as a Service (IaaS) model is by far the most challenging to defend against attacks. Indeed, an IaaS user has much more freedom than the other two cloud delivery models. An additional source of concern is that the considerable cloud resources could be used to initiate attacks against the network and the computing infrastructure.

As per Professor Dan C. Marinescu ([check this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn271884.aspx)) :

```
Imposing standards at a time when a technology is still evolving is challenging, and it can be counterproductive because it may stifle innovation. It’s important to realize the complexity of the problems posed by cloud computing and to understand the wide range of technical and social problems cloud computing raises. The effort to migrate IT activities to public and private clouds will have a lasting effect.
```

Comment: Thank you Reuben. But "private cloud" have a contradiction in its words like "single user website". It is my opinion. Cloud wisdom is to  give scalable service to public. and I think when it becomes private it degrades to an enterprise solution not a cloud one. So I'm dubious about moving of sensitive enterprise data to cloud services. And I think it will be limited to small and medium size business data.

Comment: Yes, there are many R&D is going on and we still can't say it is safe. From the sales people of my company I came to know that a majority number is still reluctant to move to cloud. So we have to wait and watch how the innovations and R&D helps it to stabilize and make it safe.